# 'expect+O+to+V ' analysis

Tags: grammar

I expect him to get over his phobia./I expect their victory./I expect to get an A.

Is 'to get over his phobia' an object?

Answer (score 1):

According to CaGEL, *expect* in the first sentence has two complements: an object *him*, and non-finite clause *to get over his phobia*.

The *to* in this case is a subordinator and thus part of the non-finite clause.

The complementation pattern is: expect + O + *to*-infinitival

No, *to get over his phobia* is not an object.

Comment: I forbade him to enter my office.

Comment: I think 'to enter my office' is an object, because 'forbade+O+O' already exists. Am I right? (But I think 'to ger over his phobia' is an object complement, because 'expec+tO+O' doesn't exist. I already thought so.)

Comment: To get over one's phobia. The question is '...to get over what?" Phobia. It is an object to the infinitive phrase 'get over'.